# Searching, Modifying and Comparing tables on Excel

Tags: database, vba, excel, excel-formula

so i have an excel problem and don't quite know how to approach it, it would be great if i could have some feedback. Basically i have 2 files:

N1) Massive DB, important columns are ID, ProductName, Score.
N2) Ranking DB. 1 Table for each city, each table has a ranking of 24 products and there are around 40 cities.

So, for each table in DB N2, i have to search every product and manually set the score so at the end, when i go to DB N1 and filter by city and sort by score, the 24 first entries are the 24 corresponding products that appear on DB N2 for that city. Products can have the same score if they are on different cities, no problem. So you could definitely set a score to each ranking position (1=9999, 2=9998, etc.).

Some tricky stuff i'm facing:

1) There are like 40 cities. And i would like to automate the process as much as i can, so i could add new cities in the future. Any ideas?

2) Some Products that appear on DB N2 are not in DB N1, so i have to point out the ProductName and the score that it should have (if the product ranked #3 for city XYZ is not on DB N1, i should note that it should have a score of 9997), so i can manually update it on the DB on the future.

I kinda have an idea how to do these things separately, but i'm having trouble putting everything together and facing the "tricky" part.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Q1) You can use ADO to open the DB Schema for the tables, then prefix or suffix the tables if neccessary to separate city tables from others, such as "CITY_LONDON" then loop these.  Look at ADO Open Schema.

Comment: q2) You need to join the 2 tables, the city table and the table in N1, with a left join, then return the null entries.  Look at SQL Joins.  Or you can use EXISTS to do this, which is more efficient, as it is a criteria, where the join will return the row, just to be checked for NULL.  Join is the easiest to master.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Power Query / Power Pivot to make each table N2 and all of the N1 tables part of a data model then create a pivot table to query the information you need. It is easy to add future cities by simply adding them to the data model then relating on the ID.

You'll probably need some calculated fields in the data model to accomplish what you need for scores not in N2 and to handle the cities as a data field.

Answer (score 0):

I finally used the free tool "Rapidminer" to play around with set operators such as Substract, append, Join, etc. That way i was able to do it in a graphic way and without having to touch code at all, so at the end it was good. Also is a really scalable solution which is a must for us.

Thanks a lot for your suggestions!